# Can't find django auth user with PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as DjangoUser
class Ward(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(DjangoUser, related_name='wards')
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='wards')
```

This is my django model and I use this filter.

```
Group.objects.filter(wards__user=_user).all()
```

I used this code in sqlite3, it works well.

But, it doesn't work in PostgreSQL.

> operator does not exist: character varying = integer
>   LINE 1: ...rchive_ward"."group_id" ) WHERE "archive_ward"."user_id" = 1

I think it is caused by `user_id` field in `archive_ward` tables.
I found this field's data type is character.varying(20).

What can I do for this code?

Comment: Do you need to make migrations? have you changed the type of field for user?

Comment: No, I didn't change django user. But I have another User Model in same `models.py`. So, I use `from django.contrib.auth.models import User as DjangoUser`.

Comment: @Sayse, I got data from other site like post, group, user, and etc.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, confused myself!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the user table in the database and adding it again.

create a new one from scratch. Syncing database again will work..

**or else You can do like this Way raw_query**

You cannot compare an integer with a varchar. PostgreSQL is strict and does not do any magic typecasting for you. I'm guessing SQLServer does typecasting automagically (which is a bad thing).

If you want to compare these two different beasts, you will have to cast one to the other using the casting syntax **::**

Answer (score 0):

The Postgres error means you're comparing an integer to a string:

```
operator does not exist: character varying = integer
```

You could change the database model so `user_id` is of an integer type.  Or you could cast the integer to string in Python:

```
Group.objects.filter(wards__user=str(_user)).all()
```

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work. Because str(_user) return username. So I do `Group.objects.filter(wards__user_id=str(_user.id)).all()`, but it has same `operator does not exist: character varying = integer`.